# Doubly linked list first fit free list malloc/free in Python

Tags: python, linked-list, memory-management, complexity

As an exercise I've implemented malloc and free in Python as a first fit [free list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_list) as described [here](https://www.gingerbill.org/article/2021/11/30/memory-allocation-strategies-005/). This tracks which blocks are free in a doubly linked list that is sorted by the address of the first byte of the block. It also keeps track of the size of each allocated block in a dictionary. The time complexity is \$O(N)\$ for both malloc and free, where \$N\$ is the number of free blocks.

```py
from typing import Optional

class Block():

    def __init__(self, size: int, address: int):
        self.address: int = address
        self.size = size
        self.prev: Optional[Block] = None
        self.next: Optional[Block] = None

    def __str__(self):
        return f"(start {self.address}, size {self.size})"

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"(start {self.address}, size {self.size})"


class Heap():

    def __init__(self, size: int):
        self.size = size
        self.head: Optional[Block] = Block(size, 0)
        self.allocation_headers: dict[int, int] = {}

    def num_free_blocks(self) -> int:
        block = self.head
        total = 0
        while block:
            total += 1
            block = block.next
        return total

    def free_size(self) -> int:
        block = self.head
        total = 0
        while block:
            total += block.size
            block = block.next
        return total

    def total_size(self) -> int:
        free = self.free_size()
        allocated = sum(self.allocation_headers.values())
        return allocated + free

    def malloc(self, size: int) -> int:
        if size <= 0:
            raise Exception
        # Sort the linked list by address
        block = self.head
        while block:
            if block.size >= size:
                self.allocation_headers[block.address] = size
                return_address = block.address
                if block.size == size:  # remove the block
                    if block.prev:
                        block.prev.next = block.next
                    if block.next:
                        block.next.prev = block.prev
                    if self.head == block:
                        self.head = block.next
                else:  # make the block smaller
                    block.address += size
                    block.size -= size
                return return_address
            block = block.next
        raise Exception

    def free(self, ptr: int):
        """
        Take an address pointer ptr and free it.
        All we need to do to free is to add an element to the free list.
        """
        free_size = self.allocation_headers[ptr]
        del self.allocation_headers[ptr]
        prev = None
        block = self.head
        while block and block.address < ptr:
            prev = block
            block = block.next
        new_block = Block(free_size, ptr)
        if not self.head:
            self.head = new_block

        if prev:
            prev.next = new_block
            new_block.prev = prev
        if block:
            block.prev = new_block
            new_block.next = block
        if self.head == block:
            self.head = new_block

        # coalesce next
        if new_block.next and new_block.next.address == (new_block.address +
                                                         new_block.size):
            new_block.size += new_block.next.size
            new_block.next = new_block.next.next
            if new_block.next:
                new_block.next.prev = new_block
        # coalesce prev
        if new_block.prev and new_block.address == (new_block.prev.address +
                                                    new_block.prev.size):
            new_block.prev.size += new_block.size
            new_block.prev.next = new_block.next
            if new_block.prev.next:
                new_block.prev.next.prev = new_block.prev
```

Example usage:

```py
def test_case_1():
    heap = Heap(1000)
    assert (heap.total_size() == 1000)
    assert (heap.num_free_blocks() == 1)
    assert (heap.free_size() == 1000)
    a = heap.malloc(100)
    assert (heap.num_free_blocks() == 1)
    assert (heap.free_size() == 900)
    assert (a == 0)
    b = heap.malloc(500)
    assert (heap.num_free_blocks() == 1)
    assert (heap.free_size() == 400)
    assert (b == 100)
    try:
        heap.malloc(950)
    except:
        pass
    heap.free(b)
    assert (heap.num_free_blocks() == 1)
    assert (heap.free_size() == 900)
    heap.free(a)
    try:
        heap.free(a)
    except:
        pass
    heap.malloc(950)
    print("Test case 1 succeeded!")
```

I believe this implementation is correct as I've fuzzed it with hundreds of millions of random inputs and all of these conditions were maintained:

```py
    def perform_checks(self):
        forward_blocks: list[Block] = []
        forward_addresses: list[int] = []
        reverse_blocks: list[Block] = []
        reverse_addresses: list[int] = []
        tail = None
        block = self.head
        forward_length = 0
        forward_free = 0
        last_address = -1
        while block:  # zoom to the end
            assert (block.address > last_address)
            forward_addresses.append(block.address)
            forward_blocks.append(block)
            forward_length += 1
            forward_free += block.size
            if not block.next:
                tail = block
            last_address = block.address
            block = block.next
        reverse_length = 0
        reverse_free = 0
        last_address = 1000000000
        if self.head is not None:
            assert (tail is not None)
        while tail:
            assert (tail.address < last_address)
            reverse_blocks.append(tail)
            reverse_addresses.append(tail.address)
            reverse_length += 1
            reverse_free += tail.size
            last_address = tail.address
            tail = tail.prev
        assert (
            forward_length == reverse_length
        ), f"Forward length of {forward_length}, Reverse length of {reverse_length}"
        reverse_blocks.reverse()
        assert (forward_blocks == reverse_blocks)
        assert (forward_free == reverse_free)
        assert (self.total_size() == self.size
                ), f"Total size {self.total_size()}, size {self.size}"
        assert (forward_length == len(forward_addresses))
```

However, I would like suggestions on improving the simplicity of the code.

The time complexity and block fragmentation could be improved by switching to a best-fit red/black tree, but let's ignore that. Assuming a flat left-to-right heap, how can we improve this and maintain the \$O(N)\$ time complexity? Could the code be dramatically cleaned up by using a Python built-in data structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trivial [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):
`__repr__()` should simply return `__str__()`.
If in future they diverge, then so be it.

Type hint nit:

```
        self.address: int = address
```

Maybe we don't need the `int` hint? Since `address`
very helpfully offers it.

And **yes**, definitely keep the hint in the signature.
It is most visible and most helpful there.

In general, I am loving your optional type hints, keep it up!
I imagine `mypy` would be happy with such an input file.

If I could criticize the whole `Optional[Block]` thing for
a moment. Maybe have your machinery *always* allocate
a 1-byte block? So there is *always* something in there?
(Yeah, I know, we leaked one byte of storage. We'll get over it.)

```
        self.allocation_headers: dict[int, int] = {}
```

I confess I do not understand the meaning of that identifier.
It seems to me that `self.allocation` would be the
natural name for such a mapping.

---

I have no idea what the usage patterns
on `num_free_blocks()` and `free_size()` are.
If, in some realistic workload, profiling
reveals they are called "a lot", consider
making them take O(1) constant time.
That is, we might choose to have the mutators maintain
statistics which could be immediately returned.

But let's return to the current O(n) linear implementation.
The two functions are nearly
[identical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).
I am a little bit sad that we don't have some
convenient iterator or other helper that they could rely on.

---

I am reading `malloc`.

```
        if size <= 0:
```

I am reading
[the spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html)

> If the size of the space requested is 0, the behavior is implementation-defined: the value returned shall be either a null pointer or a unique pointer.

Recommend you name your function something other than `malloc`
if you're not keen to support malloc semantics.

Also, we can do much better than raising a generic Exception.
Go to the trouble of subclassing it so caller will
see a diagnostic error specific to your module.
In particular, caller's `try` clause should
be able to focus on just an AllocationError.

---

This is correct:

```
                if block.size == size:  # remove the block
```

But consider relaxing that equality criterion.

Suppose that caller is creating random strings
with length between 10 and 20 characters that must be allocated.
If we **discretize** allocations to, say, multiple of 4,
then the `if` would find more opportunities to remove a block.

In deployed systems, discretizing to logarithmic boundaries
tends to be more practical.

---

In `free` there is a `while` loop and several `if`s.
Please push them down into a helper function
which computes `prev` and `block` and does some mutation.

---

Thank you for providing automated unit tests.

Please express the `+inf` constant
as `1_000_000_000` or `int(1e9)`.

---

Please improve
[PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/)
readability, perhaps by running the source through
[black](https://pypi.org/project/black).

---

> I've fuzzed it with various random inputs

> Potential off by one errors abound.

Consider making
[hypothesis](https://pypi.org/project/hypothesis)
part of your test suite.
Certainly it has taught *me* amazing things I
never would have believed before.

---

Overall?

This is good code that achieves its design goals.

I would be happy to accept or delegate maintenance tasks for it.

Coalescing allocated chunks,
at logarithmic granularity,
seems the biggest opportunity for combating the
somewhat ugly O(n) "linear cost with size of free list"
overhead. There is a rich literature describing slab, buddy,
and related allocators, likely far beyond the interests
of this project.

Pick an example workload, benchmark these library functions,
describe the results, and see where you'd like to go from there!

Comment: What a phenomenal review, thank you very much @J_H ! All of these suggestions are great. The `num_free_blocks()`, `total_size()`, and `free_size()` methods were intended only for testing that the linked list and dictionary maintained sanity in the unit tests, I should've noted this in the code. I did run the code through YAPF using the default config, this may deviate from PEP8 / I should've added a docstring to every function/method. The hypothesis library looks very interesting, I'll try it out.

Comment: The idea of discretizing the allocations is super interesting. Are we capturing this case with the else block: `else:  # make the block smaller`? Here we don't remove a block, but we do break up a larger block into the allocated portion and the leftover free space.

I believe the buddy allocation method still has a malloc time complexity of O(N). Next I'll try the red/black tree implementation of the free list, which should be O(log N) for both `malloc()` and `free()`